# Create a branch in mercurial, after changed files in tip?

Tags: mercurial, branch

I started doing some changes in a mercurial repository, without commiting them.

After 15 changed files, I've realized the changes could be a branch.

In this scenario, which would be the best way to create a branch? If I just create a new branch and move to it, could I just commit my files?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you've modified but not committed changes you need only do:

```
hg branch branch_name_you_want
```

all the `hg branch` command does is say what branch **the next** commit should be on.  You've not yet committed, so just `hg branch` and you're good.

As an example if you did this:

```
... changes ...
hg branch misspelled
hg branch correctly_spelled
hg commit
```

you'd have a branch called `correctly_spelled` and no record whatsoever of `misspelled`.